# When the schemas of database changed,how to use SqlWorkflowPersistenceService in WF?

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation

For some reasons,the schemas of database is not dbo. When using SqlWorkflowPersistenceService in WF,there would be an error found "cannnot find Stored procedure 'RetrieveNonblockingInstanceStateIds'".But if I update the procedure from "XXX.RetrieveNonblockingInstanceStateIds" to "dbo.RetrieveNonblockingInstanceStateIds"
there would be ok.How to fix it? Or how to define the default schemas in WF? I have set schemas XXX as the default schemas in current use login by asp.net in SQL 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.
I create a user without sa permissions in SQL
The stored procedure can be found
It seems that if your accout contains sa, your default schemas  cannot be personal even if you have set it.